# Server setup: Subdomain or different port for API and single or multiple ssl certificates for a docker, nginx, web and api setup?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, docker, digital-ocean

I am using `digital ocean` with `ubuntu 15.10` for my `server`. I have three `docker containers`: `nginx`, `web` (for an `angular 2` app), and `rails` for a `rails API`.

I am planning on setting up the `nginx` configuration file as follows:

`port 443` is `proxy passed` by `nginx` to my `web` app.

After that I'm a bit confused on how I should allow outside access to the `rails api`? Should I make the `rails api` accessible through a `subdomain` and if so how? Or should I just use the same domain as I do for the `web` app although with a different `port`?

Next question is do I need one `ssl certificate` for the outside world connecting with the `nginx` layer? or do I need one `ssl certificate` for the `web application` and one `ssl certificate` for the `rails api`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nginx as a load balancer for both endpoints. Something like this should be fine:

```
upstream web {
    server webcontainer1:8080;
    server webcontainer2:8080;
}

upstream api {
    server apicontainer1:5000;
    server apicontainer2:5000;
}

server {
    <your_server_directives>
    ...

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
    }
}
```

You could also do a subdomain with a separate nginx. In that case you would setup another `server` directive and do virtual hosting on the same port or another API specific port with something like:

```
upstream api {
    server apicontainer1:5000;
    server apicontainer2:5000;
}

server {
    listen 5500;
    server_name api.mydomain.com;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

In the first scenario, yes, you can get by with just one SSL certificate as the API and web will be on one port (one domain name). In the second scenario, you'd need a wildcard certificate or two certificates, one for your main web (yourdomain.com) and the api (api.yourdomain.com).

It is also worth noting that the second scenario can run into annoying CSRF issues because SSL pages generally does not allow XHR requests outside the current domain. So you can do a second subdomain for the API, but you will likely end up needing a 3rd proxy in the nginx config to proxy `yourdomain.com/api` to `api.yourdomain.com`.